# Set up Git to manage remote website

Tags: git, githooks, git-remote, git-bare

I've been trying to set up Git to manage my website, as explained per [this tutorial](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto) and [this one](https://blog.sebduggan.com/2012/03/13/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/) and [this one](https://neurobin.org/docs/web/using-git-to-manage-a-website/) and [this one](http://crosbymichael.com/how-to-manage-your-website-with-git.html) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Nilpo/8ed5e44be00d6cf21f22).

To summarize what I've done: (in-depth explanations can be found in the tutorials)

1. Set up a bare git repo on my web server in `/home/usr/mysite.git/`
2. In the bare repo, create an executable post-receive hook with `GIT_WORK_TREE` set to my web documents root, `/home/www/mysite.com/`
3. In my local git repo, add the remote repository. This is from my `.git/config` :

   ```
   [remote "live"]
   url = ssh://user@ssh.myserver.com/home/usr/mysite.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/live/*
   ```
4. Push : `git push live +master:refs/heads/master`

---

Here's the output I get:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Great!
Except it isn't : **my remote web documents root `/home/www/mysite.com/` is still empty**.
I've tried everything I could but haven't been able to push the files into my remote folder.

Do you know what I've done wrong, or what I could do to debug this?

Comment: Have you committed your changes in Git before you push?

Comment: I have! Thanks for making sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo might in fact be up-to-date. Verify that by running `git show` on your server.
Instead, maybe your post-receive hook isn't actually executed. If so, maybe because it isn't set as executable?

Comment: My hook is executable, `ls -l` says `-rwxrwxr-x` (same permissions and owner -me- as all other hooks). A weird thing I'm noticing is that all the other hooks are named `hook-name.sample`. The one I created is simple `post-receive`. Could this be relevant?

Comment: As for `git show` in my bare repo, it returns my last commits. Color is green. Does this mean it's up-to-date? Then why is my GIT_WORK_TREE folder (my website root) still empty?

Comment: Check if the hook script is actually executed. Test the script by running it manually. Or add a line in the hook script that will otherwise show (like `touch do-you-see-me`). If it doesn't, check if the executable bit is set for your hook script.

Comment: I was busy last week and just looked at my problem again today. I added the `touch` line as you suggested, and somehow the push now worked! I'm not really sure what solved it, nevertheless thank you very much for your help Lutz!

Answer (score 1):

Try `GIT_WORK_TREE` instead of `GIT_WORKING_TREE`.

Comment: Thank you Lutz! I just doubled checked and actually already had GIT_WORK_TREE. I must have mistyped my question! (I edited it)
Any other idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.git/config` should include a line starting with `push` in the section `[remote "live"]`. Otherwise it is only configured to fetch from that remote.

Comment: Could you tell me specifically what I should be adding to my `.git/config`? Something like `push = +master:refs/heads/master` ? I can't seem to find any examples of this online. Thank you!

Comment: I edited my .git/config. The git push still returns `Everything up-to-date`